# error calling stored procedure from java through callable statement

Tags: java, sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am writing a simple java program that calls a oracle stored procedure, but it doesn't work with callable statement.

When I call that stored procedure on SQLDeveloper,

```
EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(OWNNAME=>'XXXXX', TABNAME=>'XXXXX',
PARTNAME=>'XXXXXYYYYMM', ESTIMATE_PERCENT=>5, METHOD_OPT=>'FOR ALL INDEXED COLUMNS SIZE AUTO', 
CASCADE=>TRUE, DEGREE => 4);
```

it works correctly.

I already wrote other calling stored procedure methods in my java codes successfully, I simply used callable statement to call this particular stored procedure. All other methods are created stored procedures by Database admin, not the oracle system stored procedures.

```
Statement stmt = null;
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
CallableStatement cstmt = null;     
sb.append("CALL DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(OWNNAME=>'XXXXX', TABNAME=>'XXXXX', PARTNAME=>'XXXXX");
sb.append(yyyymm);
sb.append("', ESTIMATE_PERCENT=>5, METHOD_OPT=>'FOR ALL INDEXED COLUMNS SIZE AUTO', CASCADE=>TRUE, DEGREE => 4)");
cstmt = this.conn.prepareCall(sb.toString());
cstmt.execute();
```

This gives me an error like this.

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06576 : not a valid function or procedure name.
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:745)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:218)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:969)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1190)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3370)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3476)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4400)
at xxxxx.bo.batch.SYS010.SYS010.start(SYS010.java:83)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at framework.utility.classloader.DynamicClassLoader.execute(DynamicClassLoader.java:91)
at com.xxxxx.batch.module.Job.jobStart(Job.java:249)
at com.xxxxx.batch.module.Job.run(Job.java:300)
```

Could anyone give me any hint on what the real problem might be?
Does anyone have same error when calling DBMS_STATS from java source code?
Is this because of variables that I am passing within the function call?
I am using the same user account for oracle with java program and sqldeveloper.

Comment: The only way I can reproduce the error you're getting above is if I intentionally misspell the stored procedure name.

Comment: Yes, I know. I already double-checked and triple-checked but there was no typo. Also printed out on a log file what I was really calling and the only difference is the CALL instead of EXEC from SQLDeveloper. I also tried the same sql on SQLDeveloper with CALL instead of EXEC, it gave me the same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it help if you replace your `CALL` with a PL/SQL block, i.e.

```
sb.append("BEGIN");
sb.append("  DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(OWNNAME=>'XXXXX', TABNAME=>'XXXXX', PARTNAME=>'XXXXX");
sb.append(yyyymm);
sb.append("', ESTIMATE_PERCENT=>5, METHOD_OPT=>'FOR ALL INDEXED COLUMNS SIZE AUTO', CASCADE=>TRUE, DEGREE => 4);");
sb.append("END;");
```

?

(Note the extra semicolon after the stored procedure call.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Luke, I will try and post how it goes.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks a lot Luke. But I am still wondering why call isn't working for this particular statement.

Answer (score 4):

Seems the "call" syntax for Oracle requires the statement to be wrapped in braces. See the examples provided with [OracleCallableStatement](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleCallableStatement.html). Note the {} surrounding the call statement (missing in the example above):

```
CallableStatement cs1 = conn.prepareCall( "{call proc (?,?)}" ) ;
```

The example also demonstrates bind variable usage.

Comment: Worked or me with `conn.prepareStatement` - as long as I put the call in curly brackets. Example: `{ call dbms_stats.gather_index_stats(ownname=>NULL, indname=>'some_index_name') }`

Answer (score -1):

you can call procedure from java code like this:

"select GATHER_TABLE_STATS('XXXX','XXXX','XXXX') from dual" to execute the it.

HTH.

Comment: No you can't.  `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS` is a procedure, not a function, so you can't call it from SQL like this.